# What are the "Continous" and "ISO Sensitivity" settings in auto mode on a Coolpix l820?

Tags: nikon, camera-settings, coolpix

When I'm on auto mode and press menu a list of things come up; Image mode, White balance, Continuous, ISO Sensitivity, and Color options. Can some one explain more in depth what the Continuous and ISO Sensitivity does and what I should have my camera set on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see page 64-65 (or in PDF page, 84-85) in the [User Manual](http://download3.nikonimglib.com/archive1/HwYWk00T4Ffq00Y7ztR47e91ro30/L820RM_%28En%2902.pdf).

- Continuous: Allows you to capture a series of images. The available settings are
  Single (default setting), Continuous H, Continuous L, Continuous H: 120 fps, Continuous H: 60 fps, BSS, and Multi-shot 16.
- ISO sensitivity: Allows you to control the camera’s sensitivity to light. You can set
  sensitivity to Auto (default setting), or lock the setting at 125, 200, 400, 800, 1600, or 3200. When ISO sensitivity is set to Auto, the camera sets the ISO sensitivity automatically, and is displayed while shooting when ISO sensitivity increases.

With continuous, you can capture multiple images, even with continuous face detection.

With ISO, you make your camera more sensitive to light at a cost of getting more noise. Play around with this, making photos of the same subject with different ISOs and review those images on a computer at 100% magnification. In general, the smaller the ISO, the better your image quality will be. See [this link](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/camera-exposure.htm) for a quick explanation how to use the ISO setting.

(In general, to avoid getting downvotes to your questions in the future, please do your research first by consulting the User Manual or doing a quick search online.)